# Binding list to listbox and show more info of currently selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox, label

I have a class Enemy

```
public class Enemy : Entity
{
    private int _BaseAddress;
    private int _BaseOffset;
    private int _HealthOffset;
    private int _AmmoOffset;
    private int _X_Coord_Offset;
    private int _Y_Coord_Offset;
    private int _Z_Coord_Offset;

    public Enemy(int BaseAddress, int BaseOffset, int HealthOffset, int AmmmoOffset, int X_Coord_Offset, int Y_Coord_Offset, int Z_Coord_Offset)
    {
        _BaseAddress = BaseAddress;
        _BaseOffset = BaseOffset;
        _HealthOffset = HealthOffset;
        _AmmoOffset = AmmmoOffset;
        _X_Coord_Offset = X_Coord_Offset;
        _Y_Coord_Offset = Y_Coord_Offset;
        _Z_Coord_Offset = Z_Coord_Offset;
    }

    public int BaseAddress
    {
        get
        {
            int temp = BitConverter.ToInt32(ReadMemory(_BaseAddress, sizeof(int)), 0);
            return BitConverter.ToInt32(ReadMemory(temp + _BaseOffset, sizeof(int)), 0);
        }
    }

    public int Health
    {
        get
        {
            return BitConverter.ToInt32(ReadMemory(BaseAddress + _HealthOffset, sizeof(int)), 0);
        }

    }

    public int Ammo
    {
        get
        {
            return BitConverter.ToInt32(ReadMemory(BaseAddress + _AmmoOffset, sizeof(int)), 0);
        }
    }

    public float X_Coordinate
    {
        get
        {
            return BitConverter.ToSingle(ReadMemory(BaseAddress + _X_Coord_Offset, sizeof(float)), 0);
        }
    }

    public float Y_Coordinate
    {
        get
        {
            return BitConverter.ToSingle(ReadMemory(BaseAddress + _Y_Coord_Offset, sizeof(float)), 0);
        }
    }

    public float Z_Coordinate
    {
        get
        {
            return BitConverter.ToSingle(ReadMemory(BaseAddress + _Z_Coord_Offset, sizeof(float)), 0);
        }
    }

    //I know this has no value
    public string name;
}
```

And I have a list of Enemies

```
List<Enemy> list = new List<Enemy>();
```

And I have a listbox

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="lstBEnemies" Margin="20"/>
```

And I have some labels. I want that for each enemy object in the list, a listboxitem is created and the content being string name. Also when I select a listboxitem, I want that it shows me all info of the selected enemy object through the labels.

I already managed to add each item of the list to the listbox

```
for (int i = 0; i < EnemyList.Count; i++)
{
    lstBEnemies.Items.Add(EnemyList[i]);
}
```

I also already created a timer to update the info on the labels every 5ms.
My question is, what do I have to do that the info of the enemy object of the currently selecteditem is displayed via the labels?

**EDIT**:
This is how I updated the labels

```
private void DpTimerTick_GetEnemyAmmo(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbEnemyAmmoInfo.Content = EnemyList[0].Ammo;
    }
```

Comment: Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview)

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` to the `SelectedItem` of the `ListBox`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.BaseAddress, ElementName=lstBEnemies}" />
```

The corresponding binding for a Label would be:

```
<Label Content="{Binding SelectedItem.BaseAddress, ElementName=lstBEnemies}" />
```

Edit:

So why don't you simply select the appropriate item?:

```
private void DpTimerTick_GetEnemyAmmo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstBEnemies.SelectedItem = EnemyList[0];
}
```

---

```
<Label Content="{Binding SelectedItem.Ammo, ElementName=lstBEnemies}" />
```

Comment: The problem is when I use this method the labels only get the value once, it doesnt update.

Comment: They will be updated when you change the selection in the ListBox. When do you expecte them to be updated?

Comment: They should be updated every 10ms. I did that before with a timer, but how can I do this in this case

Comment: It depends on how you update them. Please show all relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Set the SelectedItem  property of the ListBox. See my edit.